# How do you use the LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder to execute a test method that has a parameter of type TestInfo?

Tags: junit5

I tried out all the different method selectors as seen on this page: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/platform/launcher/core/LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.html

For example tried to do it like so:
`selectMethod("org.example.order.OrderTests#test3")`,

like so:
`selectMethod("org.example.order.OrderTests#test3(TestInfo)")`,

or like so: `selectMethod("org.example.order.OrderTests#test3(org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TestInfoParameterResolver$DefaultTestInfo)")`

Each time, no tests are found.

When I only select the class the method resides in, it works: `selectClass("org.example.order.OrderTests")`
(but I'm looking to call the method explicitly)

I am assuming the behavior is the same for other parameter types that are resolved at runtime by a ParameterResolver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. You can select one and only one test method.
As you mentioned on this page [Discovery Selectors](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/platform/launcher/core/LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.html) there are a lot of examples.

DiscoverySelectors.selectMethod provide three way to select desired method(s)

```java
public static MethodSelector selectMethod(String className, String methodName, String methodParameterTypes) {
   ...
}

public static MethodSelector selectMethod(String className, String methodName) {
   ...
}

and

public static MethodSelector selectMethod(String fullyQualifiedMethodName) throws PreconditionViolationException {
   ...
}
```

You've tried to use the last method but the `fullyQualifiedMethodName` was wrong a little bit. If you take a look on [javadoc](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/platform/engine/discovery/DiscoverySelectors.html#selectMethod(java.lang.String)) it will turn up.
Parameter type list must exactly match and every non-primitive types must be fully qualified as well.

In your example the package is missing. Try it like: `selectMethod("org.example.order.OrderTests#test3(org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInfo)")`

Here is a short test.

```java
package io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.RepeatedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.RepetitionInfo;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInfo;

public class ClassWithTestInfo {

    @Test
    void foo() {
    }

    @Test
    void foo(TestInfo info) {
    }

    @RepeatedTest(3)
    void foo(RepetitionInfo info) {
    }
}
```

```java
package io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodBasedTestDescriptor;
import org.junit.platform.engine.DiscoverySelector;
import org.junit.platform.engine.FilterResult;
import org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectors;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.LauncherDiscoveryRequest;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.PostDiscoveryFilter;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class DiscoveryTest {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should select only the desired method(s)")
    void doTEst() {
        Assertions.assertAll(
                () -> {
                    var methods = discover(DiscoverySelectors.selectClass(ClassWithTestInfo.class));
                    Assertions.assertEquals(3, methods.size());
                },
                () -> {
                    // your way
                    var fqmn = "io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow.ClassWithTestInfo#foo(TestInfo)";
                    var methods = discover(DiscoverySelectors.selectMethod(fqmn));
                    Assertions.assertEquals(0, methods.size());
                },
                () -> {
                    // good way
                    var fqmn = "io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow.ClassWithTestInfo#foo(org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInfo)";
                    var methods = discover(DiscoverySelectors.selectMethod(fqmn));
                    Assertions.assertEquals(1, methods.size());
                }
        );
    }

    private List<Method> discover(DiscoverySelector... selectors) {
        final List<Method> methodCollector = new ArrayList<>();
        LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
                .selectors(selectors)
                .filters((PostDiscoveryFilter) object -> {
                    Method m = ((MethodBasedTestDescriptor) object).getTestMethod();
                    methodCollector.add(m);
                    return FilterResult.included("Matched");
                })
                .build();
        LauncherFactory.create().discover(request);

        return methodCollector;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're 100% right, I didn't specify the correct fully qualified parameter type name. The issue was that I just copied the result of calling testInfo.getClass().getTypeName() inside of a test method which returns something very different. Thanks a lot for your detailed answer!